# Why can't I assign a probability measure to this class?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega =
(0,1]$ and ${\cal A}$ be $\emptyset$ and all *finite* unions of disjoint intervals of the form
$(a,a')$, $0\leq a\leq a'\leq 1$. Now ${\cal A}$ is a field but not a $\sigma$-field since it
isn't closed under countable unions.

It seems to me that every element of ${\cal A} -\emptyset$ has a well defined notion of length (add up the lengths of the disjoint intervals that make it up), and we can define $\emptyset$ to have a length
of $0$. So why isn't this a valid probability measure? If it is indeed a valid probability measure, then what is the most general kind of class to which one can assign a probability measure and if, as I suspect, I am missing something and this is not a valid measure, would you please explain what I am missing?

Comment: Just so you know, the empty set and the Greek letter phi are not the same thing

Comment: Isn't this just Lebesgue measure, restricted to a particular subcollection of (measurable) sets? And do you have a particular reason why you don't want to consider the full $\sigma$-algebra of all measurable sets?

Comment: I was just trying to figure out why  "probabilities" can only be defined on $\sigma$-fields.  It seemed to be  the example above also admitted a sensible definition.

Comment: @Novice thank you. ok, the null set is a set of measure zero and the empty set is a set with no elements. Right?

Comment: @aflatoonpista Yes. Depending on the particular space in question, there can be non-empty sets with zero measure, like the rational numbers or the Cantor set.

Comment: Well, the key axiom for measures is $\sigma$-additivty, so that gets a bit harder to deal with if you're only closed under finite unions. There are finitely additive "measures", (though, lacking $\sigma$-additivity, they are often only called "set functions"), but countable unions and additivity seem to have the right balance of having enough interesting examples and being able to prove interesting things about to have become the standard axiom set.

Answer (score 1):

Measures are by definition defined on $\sigma$-fields. There are more general non-negative set functions (namely contents and premeasures) defined on more general collections of subsets (algebras, rings, semirings, $\pi$-systems, ...). See sections 1.1 and 1.2 of *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* by Klenke for a fairly detailed discussion of these topics.